# What does "feel one's stomach disappear" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Harry Potter:

> Harry ran up the hall into the kitchen and **felt his stomach disappear.**
>
> Aunt Petunia’s masterpiece of a pudding, the mountain of cream and sugared violets, was floating up near the ceiling. On top of a cupboard in the corner crouched Dobby.

Comment: I think it means *Harry was stunned by what he had seen* (described in the following paragraph).

Comment: Without further context, because this is from a fantasy series, it could also be taken literally. His stomach could have *actually* disappeared due to some spell. However, I've read the series, and I don't recall that ever actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is a metaphor that the author invented.  I think it means Harry was so stunned that he could feel it in his stomach.